# как в DataFrame записать большое количество строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, оптимизация, dataframe

Имеется list **df** , в нем содрежится 193270 строк, есть ли быстрый способ записать их в DataFrame?

как делаю я:

```
s = pd.DataFrame()
for i in tqdm_notebook(np.arange(0,len(df))):
    s = pd.concat([s,df[i]])
```

Запись идет, но чем больше строк в DataFrame, тем медленнее запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно сейчас показывает 4 часа записи, и это значение растет.

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `df` - это список, как написано у вас в вопросе, то DataFrame можно создать так:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

В любом случае добавлять 193270 строк в DataFrame *по одной* - самый медленный и неэффективный способ.

Вызывая `pd.concat([s,df[i]])` 193270 раз, вы 193270 раз создаете новый DataFrame и копируете в него все данные из `s`, по мере работы цикла число строк в `s` постоянно растёт - как следствие цикл будет работать все медленнее.

Comment: нет, df это list

Comment: @mr.suhinin2017, решение в ответе: `s = pd.DataFrame(df)`